# Handle Image update in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Hi everyone i am using `FileInput` kartik widget in `yii2` project and uploading and saving works fine but i am having problem while updating the images

I can get the images path on the update form and create and array and display in as `initialpreview` in the widget but the problem is that my `files` field is required field so even there are some values in `initialpreview` the form gives error to upload image as its required field. So what should i do here?

I only want to give preview of their uploaded pics to the user but if they dont make any changes than i dont want to update anything for images

Following is my `view` code and `model` code

```
return [
        [[ 'price', 'created_date', 'created_by', 'updated_date', 'updated_by','file','address'], 'required'],
        [['price'], 'number'],
        [['address'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['file'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'maxFiles' => 4],
    ];


  <?php
   $initalpreview = array();
   foreach($model->adsImages as $images) {
      $initalpreview[] = Html::img('/upload/'.$images->image, ['class'=>'file-preview-image']);
   }

   ?>
 <?=$form->field($model, 'file[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*',
    'multiple'=>true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'maxFileCount' => 5,
        'initialPreview'=> $initalpreview,
        'showUpload' => false,
    ]
]); ?>
```

So what should i do here?

Thank you

Comment: what about using a scenario for action update ?

Comment: @AjithN actually i dont know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this

In Model create a scenario named 'update' and mention the fields that are required when update action works

```
return [
        [['price', 'created_date', 'created_by','updated_date','updated_by','address'], 'required', 'on' => 'update'],
    ];
```

Now inside controller action update call the scenario

```
public function  actionUpdate(){

 //Model Declaration

        $model->scenario = 'update';

  // update code

    }
```